# getting error React does not recognize the `handleChange` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make one `login form` in react .but I am getting this error

**React does not recognize the `handleChange` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `handlechange` instead.**

**input value is also not setting input field** when I type in `input` field it is not updating the state why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-clarke-qbkjw

```
<form noValidate>
      <TextBox
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        type="text"
        helperText="Assistive text"
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleMouseDownPassword={handleMouseDownPassword}
        value={userId}
      />
      <TextBox
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        type="password"
        helperText="Assistive text"
        value={password}
        showPassword={showPassword}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleClickShowPassword={handleClickShowPassword}
        handleMouseDownPassword={handleMouseDownPassword}
      />
      <div className="button-group">
        <button>LOGIN</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `TextBox` component you're passing all the props from the parent via `{...props}`. Considering that `TextField` itself doesn't have `handleChange` property, I assume it passes it down to the underlying input DOM element, which doesn't recognise that prop.

What you can do is to extract the props used inside `TextBox` and collect the rest using the rest argument, so you don't end up passing unnecessary props down:

```
export default function TextBox({handleChange, handleClickShowPassword, handleMouseDownPassword, value,  ...props}) {
```

Another option is to remove `{...props}` from the `TextField` component and explicitly pass all the necessary props.

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-northcutt-og5l7)

Comment: but values are not setting in input field why //?

Comment: whatever I am typing it is not reflecting

Comment: ...!! see `his synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `nativeEvent` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). `

Comment: I am getting this warning when I am trying to type anything in textfield

Comment: textfield value is not updating

Comment: That's because you're setting `value` but pass `userId` as a prop. Updated the codesandbox link.

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't like uppercase letters in the prop names. Instead of passing "handleChange", pass "handlechange". You will get a similar error for "handleMouseDownPassword".

Regarding the input issue, I don't think you've provided enough context. But you have to have a handleChange method to update the state each time the field is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the **handleChange()** function, you were only setting the VALUE state, you need to set the state userId when you write on the first input, and the password when you write to the second input

At b.js add props name={stateName} so the handleChange() can know which input is controlling

***Check Demo for more:***
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-heisenberg-z4q4z

(other answeres explained why you are getting that error in console ...props)